# How to trigger a method if users don't click on Button in Android after a delay of time

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am making an android application in its layout, I have 4 buttons

```
<Button
    style="@style/Tile"
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:onClick="b1"/>

<Button
    style="@style/Tile"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:onClick="b2"/>

<Button
    style="@style/Tile"
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:onClick="b3"/>

<Button
    style="@style/Tile"
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:onClick="b4"/>
```

And i want to trigger a method if user does not interact with them within 20 seconds, and also if user interact the method will be different.
can you please help me solve this problem, or guide me where should i look for solution.

Comment: you can use **Handler** class with **postDelay** for achiving this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a `Runnable`. This will get executed if the `Button` will not get clicked in 20 seconds:

```
final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // do something
        aMethod();
    }
};
```

Create a `Handler` and post the `Runnable` with a delay of 20 seconds:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(runnable, 20000);
```

If the `Button` gets clicked, call `removeCallbacks()` on the `Handler` instance, which will effectively remove the pending `Runnable` from the `Handler`'s message queue:

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
        // do your Button stuff
        anotherMethod();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Below logic will trigger method `processAfterDelayed()` after delay specified in Handler once the Activity is pushed. You can modify this logic for your specific requirement!

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

      @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view);

        Handler handlerTimer = new Handler();
        handlerTimer.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                processAfterDelayed();
            }
        }, 1500);
    }

    void processAfterDelayed(){
    //your logic
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@Jay you can use code which explained by @Stallion
Just put performClick method you will be able to click on view

```
void processAfterDelayed(){
    button1.performClick();
}
```